# add replica or move replica on new node using Pysolr

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, solr, pysolr, solr7

I want to add replicas to new instances using PySolr/or via api calls.

Scenario: For updating AMIs of EC2 instances on which Solr is running with 0 downtime, I have planned to add new instances(with new AMI) add replica on new instances and then decommision the old replicas and instances once the replicas have copied successfully on new instances

I am trying to do this using PySolr. Can someone guide on how new replicas are added using PySolr: https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr/tree/5c3a68447734e77be9e9648b184f8d600fd661c5

if it is not possible via PySolr can this be done by solrpy or [Simple Python](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/using-python.html#simple-python)

Can something like Autoscaling be achived by PySolr? https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/solrcloud-autoscaling-overview.html#quick-start-automatically-adding-replicas

I am new to Solr, examples will be very aprreciated

Thank you